# How to live stream to UPnP media renderer TV?

Tags: video-streaming, upnp, dlna

I would like to stream live audio-video from my PC with camera over LAN to TV supporting DLNA/UPnP.

Questions:

1. How to get my TV to play my HLS/UDP/RTSP stream
2. How can I detect what formats/playlist are supported on my TV?

I can play video from HTTP
I can play video from Media Server
I have successfully used SetAVTransportURI for these.
But when I use m3u8 playlist, or RTSP, TV says unknown format.
I can control TV from Home Assistant or curl upnp request.
I can create streaming server using VLC, ffmpeg, gstreamer, icecast ...
I think it should be possible because TV can play live youtube, netflix streams. It is Philips TV with its SAPHI OS.